# C# Google Drive API list of files from my personal drive

Tags: .net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I am trying to connect to my own personal Google Drive account and gather a list of file names.

What I have done:

1. Installed all the NuGet packages required
2. Added Google Drive to the API Manager in Google Developers Console
3. Setup a [Service Account](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#serviceaccounts) and downloaded a P12 key for authentication
4. Wrote the following code to call the API:

   ```
   string EMAIL = "myprojectname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com";
   string[] SCOPES = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\\DriveProject.p12",
                                  "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
   ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
      new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(EMAIL) { 
        Scopes = SCOPES 
      }.FromCertificate(certificate)
   );

   DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { 
      HttpClientInitializer = credential
   });

   FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
   IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;
   if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
       foreach (var file in files)
           sb.AppendLine(file.Name);
   ```

This code seems to be working fine.  The problem is I only get a single file returned, it is named "Getting started.pdf" and I have no idea where the hell it is coming from.  I think the problem is clearly that my personal Google Drive account is not wired up to this code.  How do I get this call to return the files from my personal Google Drive account?

The only help I was able to find was trying to get you to access *any* end users Google Drive account in your interface.  My scenario is different than that.  I only want to connect to *my* Google Drive account behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are connecting with a service account which does **not** connect to your personal google drive account.  Think of a service account as its own user, it has its own Google drive account.  Which by running files.list apparently right now doesn't have any files on it.

**Solution 1:**

Upload some files to the Service accounts Google drive account

**Solution 2:**

Take the service account email address and share a folder on your google drive account with the service account like you would any other user.   I am not sure if its possible to share a full drive account or not.  Let me know if you manage to share the root folder :)

*Update for comment: Open google drive the web site.   right click the folder click share with others.  Add the service account email address.  Boom it has access.*

**Solution 3:**

Switch to Oauth2 authenticate the code once where by you get a refresh token anytime you run the application there after just use that refresh token to gain access to your personal drive account.

*Update for comment: You will have to authenticate it manually once.  After that the client library will load the refresh token for you.  Its stored on the machine.*

**Oauth2 Drive v3 sample code:**

```
/// <summary>
/// This method requests Authentcation from a user using Oauth2.  
/// Credentials are stored in System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
/// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
/// </summary>
/// <param name="clientSecretJson">Path to the client secret json file from Google Developers console.</param>
/// <param name="userName">Identifying string for the user who is being authentcated.</param>
/// <returns>DriveService used to make requests against the Drive API</returns>
public static DriveService AuthenticateOauth(string clientSecretJson, string userName)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            throw new Exception("userName is required.");
        if (!File.Exists(clientSecretJson))
            throw new Exception("clientSecretJson file does not exist.");

        // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them
        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };                   // View and manage the files in your Google Drive         
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/apiName");

            // Requesting Authentication or loading previously stored authentication for userName
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                     scopes,
                                                                     userName,
                                                                     CancellationToken.None,
                                                                     new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Drive Authentication Sample",
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Create Oauth2 DriveService failed" + ex.Message);
        throw new Exception("CreateOauth2DriveFailed", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  Solution 1 is not an option but the other two sound perfect.  The caveat for solution 2 is not an issue for me because I do not wish to iterate through the root Google Drive directory anyways.

Comment: I just need a little more guidance.  For #2 you say "share a folder on your google drive account with the service account like you would any other user" and I am not sure how to proceed with this.  I do not have any *other users* so if you could please clarify this I would appreciate it!  For #3 I am not sure how to acquire the refresh token you mention.  Since my code runs in a service, I can't really imagine a way for it to bring up Google interface and allow me to login for the first time.  Is there an easy way to manually grab one of these tokens?  If so, do they expire?  Thank you again!

Comment: as long as you don't change the username you send it with Oauth2 will use the same credentials but credentials can still fail.   Really I would go with nr 2 if you can.

Comment: Thank you for the edits!!!  I agree #2 sounds like the way to go.  One little tidbit that I am slightly confused about: so this email address (in my code "myprojectname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com") actually has a Google Drive account?  What is the password for that?  I don't remember setting a password for it.  If someone gets the password for this account will they be able to login through the Google Drive Interface and see all the files?

Comment: Its a dummy user it doesn't have a password you cant login to it like that .   The password is more the key file you downloaded from google it can only be accessed though the API.    If someone gets the Keyfile and the service account email address they could use the API to access your drive account.   This is again not though the website.   Service accounts can only be used programmatically

Comment: a tutorial I wrote with way more info then you want to know http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help today!  This is my first time working with Google API so I appreciate the helping hand.  Your web site looks very helpful and I have bookmarked it for further reference.

Comment: Now you know where to find me if you get stuck.  There isn't much documentation on drive v3 for .net yet but  if you get stuck I have some sample stuff you can try.