# Google Service Account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to connect my server written in C# to my Google Drive and therefore I use Google Service Account, I configured everything from Google API Console and have the following code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2("client_secret.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        try
        {
            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("sp-update@salmon-player-update.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
                {
                    Scopes = Scopes
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));
            DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Salmon Player Update"
            });
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.PageSize = 10;
            listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

            // List files.
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
                .Files;
            Console.WriteLine("Files:");
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

But whatever I do I'm getting only "Getting Started" file which does not exist there anymore. I have a lot of different files which I cannot access to.
Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service account is its own user, so it will have its own Drive account space. If you want to access files from your personal account, you will have to either a) share those files with your service account's email address or b) use an OAuth flow and authenticate with your own user rather than the robot service account.

Comment: But it is also somehow bound to my personal account by which I have opened service account, no?

Comment: And how do they share the drive space between my personal account and service account

Comment: No, it's not bound to your personal account in anyway. If you want to share Drive space, I suggest creating a folder in your personal Drive space and "sharing" it with the service account so that it has full read and write access.

Comment: The service account is associated with the project you created in Google API Console, but this association is only used for monitoring and billing (if applicable) your API calls.

Comment: Is there any possibility to explore the service account storage besides API calls, I mean with google drive UI?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: For implementation purpose, check this [previous SO ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36029525/5995040). Daimto provided 3 solution to connect your personal account to a service account; First - upload files to the service account drive, Second - Share a folder to the service account (like how you share to other users) and Lastly - user OAuth2 to get the refresh token and use it to gain access to your personal account. You can also check his [5 part drive tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/)